# Instance of Windowsformapp repeatedly creates an executable in the temp folder called "Velo.exe" in Windows 10

Tags: windows, virus, temporary-files, trojan, winforms

Since yesterday, I have noticed that through Windows Form an application called Velo.exe creates many subfolders (2-3 per minute, see photo) in the Temp folder with the same file called Velo.exe inside: I have tried to stop the instance of Windowsformapp, but the application always restarts. What is the problem? What can I do to solve the problem? I have uploaded one of the Velo.exe files [here](https://we.tl/t-J0TKYKVxl9). I have been told that it could be a [trojan virus](https://vms.drweb-av.it/virus/?i=18420177).

[image]

Here is the log I find in \AppData\Local\Microsoft\CLR_v4.0\UsageLogs\Velo.exe.log:

1,"fusion","GAC",0
1,"WinRT","NotApp",1
3,"System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System\43b97e99fab55055761ec7618b2bf77b\System.ni.dll",0
3,"System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Drawing\98b511e858932d0d2ded15adaa4551a5\System.Drawing.ni.dll",0
3,"System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Windows.Forms\ba73c84262a3c3e850b5811664dd4b05\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll",0

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you suspect it's a trojan take the necessary steps to remove it from your system.

Comment: I've tried everything and run scans, remove the file, clean up logs, but the application always reactivates: what can I do to get rid of it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you uploaded the binary to something more mainstream like VirusTotal

Comment: Here: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/e8ee296ceff0c7344014a9bf0095644602ab96ec139601aa5aa82cb9ffb974e7/behavior/C2AE

Comment: I would use AutoRuns and the registry editor to see how the application is being automatically installed, while the behavior is odd, the fact only off brand security vendors are detecting it as malicious tells me it's not actually malicious.  '

Comment: I deactivated everything related to Velo.exe with Autoruns and deleted all related registry keys, but it keeps starting and replicating itself

Comment: I found a key "PendingFileRenameOperations" with the names of the folders created by Velo.exe in temp in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager and Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager